# Ember-Cli (0.40) assets when deploying to heroku

Tags: heroku, ember.js, ember-cli

I am deploying and ember-cli app to heroku and pretty much everything is working as hoped.  The only issue is that when the app precompiles, it adds a fingerprint to images and assets as expected but does not add them to the asset reference within a stylesheet.  Specifically, I have a couple of images as background images in stylesheets that when deployed can't be found due to the addition of the fingerprint to the file.  How do I either get the fingerprint added to the asset path reference in the stylesheet or tell ember/heroku to not add fingerprint to any files?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

A little late getting back to this but I ended up just disabling the fingerprinting for now by adding this in the Brocfile.js

```js
var app = new EmberApp({
  fingerprint: {
    enabled: false
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to **upgrade to the latest version** of Ember CLI. From version **0.1.3** of Ember CLI there's no need to disable fingerprint. I think it's fixed by [this pull request](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/pull/2535).

[According to Ember CLI guide](http://www.ember-cli.com/#upgrading-an-ember-cli-app) steps to upgrade to the latest version of Ember CLI are included with each release and can be found [here](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/releases).

Before upgrade, I had issues with Lightbox2 and Fancybox(image assets). After upgrade, all references to fingerprinted assets are applied correctly.